# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: block is never being called

Tags: ios5, asynchronous, block

The program flow never reaches the Block with NSLog-Message. Am I missing something here?

```
[NSURLConnection 
    sendAsynchronousRequest:req  
    queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
    completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response_, NSData *data_, NSError *error_) {
         NSLog(@"Why am I not being called %@", data_);
    }];
```

Comment: Are you sure? If you're just testing this in a unit test, then the test exits before the callback gets invoked. Try adding this after it: [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];